# How to pass the where clause to a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a web page, there user can select the column and filter the column and when they click the search button, it has to call the stored procedure by passing the complete where clause.

I think it such a bad idea to pass the where clause on stored procedure, because it may cause SQL injection.

This is my page

[image: Filter Page]

Is there any other way to my criteria? I should pass the value with operator. Because user may choose different comparison operator in different situation

Answer (score 1):

This would indeed be a very bad practice to pass such a where clause. There are few options:

1. Use Entity Framework to build raw queries
2. Use [table-valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) to stored procedures

   - It could contain three columns: `Condition`, `Column`, `Value`
   - So you build this vable variable in your code and send it to SQL Server stored procedure where based on these values, you can build your query dynamically.
3. There must be some other solutions, but these are the first proper ones that come to my mind.

Comment: May I create like this `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]
@whereSql nvarchar(256)

AS
    EXEC('SELECT [fields] FROM [table] WHERE ' + @whereSql)
GO`

Comment: @Abbas Wouldn't recommend.