# Pass an extended where clause in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a stored procedure which would enable users to pass the filters (columns and conditions) as per their choice. Since the number of columns in the table, the idea is to pass the where condition in whole as a single input parameter rather than multiple parameters associated with each column. Below is a snippet of the procedure.

```
create or replace procedure "USER_SANDBOX"."TRY".dummy(input string)
returns table()
language sql
as
$$
  declare
    res resultset;
    query varchar default 'select *,lead(last_date,1,null) over(partition by id order by last_date) next_date from reporting.table 
    where' || :input;
  begin
    res := (execute immediate :query);
    return table (res);
  end;
$$
;
```

The SQL representation of input (which would be the entire where clause) I would want in my CALL statement is below:

```
substring(last_date,1,10)='2022-12-15' and tags='[Same_Slice_01]' and project='Health'
```

I am calling the above procedure with the mentioned where clause as below:

```
CALL "USER_SANDBOX"."TRY".dummy('substring\(last_date\,1\,10\)\=\'2022-12-15\' and tags\=\'[Same_Slice_01]\' and project\=\'Health\'')
```

The above CALL statement errors out with - Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR.

Can someone help with the way to escape characters in the CALL statement.

The above procedure is written in Snowflake (classic console UI)

Comment: Your input starts with the word WHERE but you already have WHERE in your code. When debugging code like this I would always start by getting the SP to return the final SQL statement rather than executing it

Comment: The CALL statement does not start with a WHERE clause

Comment: I didn’t say anything about the CALL statement. In your code you have “ where' || :input; “ and the input value you’ve provided starts with “ where substring(last_date,1,10) …”. So, as I said, you have the word “where” repeated twice

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. The where is a sql representation of my input parameter I want in my CALL statement. My SP ends with where and the CALL statement doesn't start with where but with the filter conditions following it. Hope this clears the confusion:)

Comment: Edited it to clear the confusion!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass the where clause to a SQL Server stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049925/how-to-pass-the-where-clause-to-a-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

Its best not to do this, pass in parameters and put them in a where clause.

you can use 'and (@param is null or @param = x)' as the clauses that will skip any parameters that are not passed in, however if you're trying much more complex things than that, then your best option is really to create the query dynamically and use it directly in the client.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Agreed it's not an elegant way but I'm not aware if it is possible to dynamically generate the SQL as the user has the flexibility to change the filter column names and the conditions as well (neither the number of columns nor the column names nor the filter criteria on the chosen columns are in control).

Answer (score 0):

Echoing the previous answer that passing in text like this is probably not "safe" and also noting that if you want to use the result from this code you probably want to create a function, not a procedure, something like this should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dummy(input string)
RETURNS TABLE ()
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
  query VARCHAR;
  res RESULTSET;
BEGIN
  query := 'select * from mytable1 where ' || input;
  res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query);
  RETURN TABLE(res);
END;

call dummy('code = \'Y\'');
```